# подсчитать автоматическими средствами выражение, заданное в виде текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Подскажите, возможно ли в голом питоне или с помощью каких-либо дополнительных библиотек сделать следующее:

вычислить выражение, записанное в виде строки, например:

```
(3 + 7) * 5 + 8
```

т.е. вызвать какую-нибудь функцию `calculate()`

```
value = calculate('(3 + 7) * 5 + 8')
print(value) # = 58
```

Конечно можно самому все это распарсить, но лучше, если бы существовали уже готовые средства

Comment: Толи я дурак, толи лыжи не едут. Может я чего то не понял, но просто уберите calculate и одну скобку в начале, другую в конце. Тогда все работает

Comment: `eval` и `exec` :)

Comment: блин, мог бы и догадаться JS приему :)

Comment: Вы же знаете что они очень опасны?

Comment: только когда в них появляется что-то большее чем плюс и минус :)

Comment: просто предупредил

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать модуль Sympy

```
import sympy


x = sympy.symbols("x")
func = lambda x: input() + "-x"

print(sympy.solve(func(x)))
```

---

Либо так:

```
with open("file.py", "w") as file:
    file.write(f"x = {input()}")
    
import file
print(file.x)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Eval / exec

Внимание: опасное решение.

```
print(eval("(3 + 7) * 5 + 8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
from tkinter import *
import math

root = Tk()

class Calc:
    def __init__(self,master):
        root.title("Calculator")
        
        for i in range (6):
            root.columnconfigure(i, minsize=50)

        for c in range (5):
            root.rowconfigure(c, minsize=50)                    

        self.E = Entry(root, font=("Calibri", 24), justify=RIGHT)
        self.E.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6, pady=3, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        self.E.focus_set()
        #BUTTONS
        Button(root, width="3", text="0", command=lambda:self.action(0)).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="1", command=lambda:self.action(1)).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="2", command=lambda:self.action(2)).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="3", command=lambda:self.action(3)).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="4", command=lambda:self.action(4)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="5", command=lambda:self.action(5)).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="6", command=lambda:self.action(6)).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="7", command=lambda:self.action(7)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="8", command=lambda:self.action(8)).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="9", command=lambda:self.action(9)).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        
        Button(root, width="3", text="C", command=lambda:self.clear1()).grid(row=1, column=5, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="AC", command=lambda:self.clear_all()).grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="+", command=lambda:self.action("+")).grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="-", command=lambda:self.action("-")).grid(row=3, column=3, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="x", command=lambda:self.action("x")).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="÷", command=lambda:self.action("÷")).grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text=".", command=lambda:self.action(".")).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="=", command=lambda:self.equals()).grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="(", command=lambda:self.action("(")).grid(row=2, column=4, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text=")", command=lambda:self.action(")")).grid(row=2, column=5, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="√", command=lambda:self.squareroot()).grid(row=3, column=4, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="x²", command=lambda:self.square()).grid(row=3, column=5, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")
        Button(root, width="3", text="%", command=lambda:self.action("%")).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S")

        menu = Menu()
        root.config(menu=menu)

        pref = Menu(menu)
        pref.add_command(label="Settings", command=lambda:self.settings())
        pref.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda:root.destroy())
        menu.add_cascade(label="Preferences", menu=pref)

        help = Menu(menu)
        help.add_command(label="About", command=lambda:self.about())
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)

    def settings(self):
        win_settings = Tk()
        Button(win_settings, text="Done", command=lambda:win_settings.destroy()).grid()
        win_settings.mainloop()
        
    def about(self):
        win_about = Tk()
        Button(win_about, text="Done", command=lambda:win_about.destroy()).grid()
        win_about.mainloop()

    def action(self, button_type):
        self.E.insert(END, button_type)
    
    def clear_all(self):
        self.E.delete(0, END)
    
    def clear1(self):
        self.text = self.E.get()[:-1]
        self.E.delete(0, END)
        self.E.insert(0, self.text)
    
    def getandreplace(self):
        self.replaced_text = self.E.get().replace("÷",'/')
        self.replaced_text = self.replaced_text.replace('x','*')
        return self.replaced_text
   
    def equals(self):
        self.getandreplace()
        try:
            self.value = eval(self.replaced_text)
        except SyntaxError or NameError or ZeroDivisionError:
            self.E.delete(0, END)
            self.E.insert(0, "Invalid input!")
        else:
            self.E.delete(0, END)
            self.E.insert(0, self.value)
    
    def square(self):
        self.getandreplace()
        try:
            self.value = eval(self.replaced_text)
        except SyntaxError or NameError:
            self.E.delete(0, END)
            self.E.insert(0, "Invalid input!")
        else:
            self.sq_val = math.pow(self.value,2)
            self.E.delete(0, END)
            self.E.insert(0, self.sq_val)
    
    def squareroot(self):
        self.getandreplace()
        try:
            self.value = eval(self.replaced_text)
        except SyntaxError or NameError:
            self.E.delete(0, END)
            self.E.insert(0, "Invalid input!")
        else:
            sqrt_val = math.sqrt(value)
            self.E.delete(0, END)
            self.E.insert(0, sqrt_val)
    

calc_class = Calc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]